# ejb - Singleton lock mode when calling methods of same instance?

Tags: java, singleton, ejb

Here is my singleton class:

```
import javax.ejb.Lock;
import javax.ejb.LockType;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;


@Singleton
public class TestSingletons implements TestSingletonsRemote{

    @Lock(LockType.READ)
    @Override
    public void foo(int id) {
        bar(id);
    }


    private void bar(int id){
        // do stuff
    }

}
```

The method `foo` has a `LockType.READ`, so it can be accessed concurrently. `foo` actually does nothing but calls a private method of the class `bar` which is not annotated, so by default It should have a `LockType.WRITE` lock mode.

The question, as you might guess from the above scenario, is:
Will the call to `foo` be practically concurrent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `bar` method is private, it's not a business method.

Default `LockType.WRITE` is only applicable for business methods.

Comment: So you're saying **Yes**

Comment: Yes, the LockType should be just READ

Comment: More importantly, the call from foo to bar is not an EJB method call.  Even if bar was public, the call from foo to bar would still not be an EJB method call, so bar (in this scenario only) would still be running under foo's READ concurrency.  In order to get WRITE, you would need to self-inject the bean (or use SessionContext.getBusinessObject) and invoke the public bar on that proxy.